# How to get Robot framework Process library to properly read output from a resource .py file

Tags: python, robotframework

Trying to get robot framework to properly be able to validate the result of a basic .py file.

I have a simple Hello World python file in a resource directory.
My .robot file looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   Process
 
*** Test Case ***
We should print to a command line.
  ${result}=    run process   python    -c    ../Resources/helloWorld.py
  Should Be Equal   ${result.stdout}    Hello World.
```

The helloWorld.py file is just print("Hello World.")

Directory structure would look like this:

```
Root
-tests
--test.robot
-Resources
--hellowWorld.py
```

But when I execute the test I receive a fail with the result: != Hello World.

Comment: Did you have a look at what is in the result? is the ${result.stderr} empty?

Answer (score 1):

Found that it wasn't able to find the directory using relative path, ended up needing to use the full path.

stdout was just logging | FAIL |

So I logged the stderr and found that it was throwing a syntax error. After some trial and error of tweaking the path and escaping all my slashes, it was able to run how I was expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you use "log" to see what your "${result}" is, I doubt that the robot can get the content that you printed in python. Second, I think you should try "Should Be Equal As Strings"